# Ошибка aiogram:Bot: Тестирование [@testaavobot] WARNING:aiogram:Updates were skipped successfully. INFO:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Start polling

Tags: python, aiogram, telebot

**Почему выдает ошибку
INFO:aiogram:Bot: Тестирование [@testaavobot]
WARNING:aiogram:Updates were skipped successfully.
INFO:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Start polling.
через библиотеку telebot нет ошибок и все работает ок, но все же aiogram получше telebot. Но не как не могу начать писать код и тестить бота из этой ошибки. Буду очень благодарен если поможете.**

```
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

API_TOKEN = 'ЗДЕСЬ ВВЕЛ свой токен'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Hi!\nI'm EchoBot!\nPowered by aiogram.")



@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(message.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Это - не ошибка.

Слово `INFO:` в начале может подсказать, что это информационное сообщение. Конкретно в этом случае бот говорит, что он пропустил уже существующие запросы и начал работу.

Это очень полезная функция, особенно во время дебаггинга. Но злоупотреблять логированием не стоит - не надо делать лог каждого сообщения.